# Prepending a 1 to outbound Caller ID FreePBX

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I use FreePBX as an SBC for an older switch we use. The older switch can only send 10 digits as outbound caller id, while our SIP provider requires 11 digits for STIR attestation.

I have tried adding the following to /etc/asterisk/extensions_custom.conf:

```
[macro-dialout-one-predial-hook]
exten => _X.,1,NoOp(Entering user defined context macro-dialout-trunk-predial-hook in extensions_custom.conf)
exten => _X.,n,GotoIf($["${LEN(${CALLERID(num)})} = 10]?addone)
exten => _X.,n,MacroExit
exten => _X.,n(addone),Set(CALLERID(num)=1${CALLERID(num)})
exten => _X.,n,MacroExit
```

But it is not working. Pretty new to working with dialplans, not sure what is wrong.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe today is the day its worth upgrading your switch?

Comment: I would have just done that if it were possible.

Comment: I see, well just rarely does anyone "need" to upgrade a switch but in this type of instance it makes sense, but also, clients seem to have unending problems but very limited resources to deal with them.    Hope you find a work around!  Maybe there is a possible patch or firmware upgrade for the switch?

Answer (score 0):

That is simple : macro-dialout-one-predial-hook is for dial to  one EXTENSION. You have use macro-dialout-trunk* dialplan.

Just open your asterisk console, learn how to see which lines are running, read it. It is really simple.

But in general, if you are doing SBC on asterisk(which is not so nice idea actually, it is not SBC), you should write simple 10-20 lines dialplan and it will cover all your need. Freepbx is PBX, it will just waste your resources.

Or hire someone.